# Creating a backup system with btrfs deduplication

Tags: backup, archiving, btrfs

I'm thinking about making my own archive/backup solution. This sounds like a bad idea, but I can't see another way to meet my requirements.

I have three Windows PCs I'd like to backup. They contain my work data and family pictures. Total is about 2 TiB and increasing. I'm worried about direct data loss (disk drives crashing), but also about data corruption (ransomware).

I was thinking to make a linux server with a btrfs partition. Every week, I'd copy all data to a new directory, and then run an offline btrfs deduplication action to conserve disk space. The layout would then look like

```
backup_pictures
  20170601
     file1.jpg
     file2.jpg
  20170608
     file1.jpg
     file2.jpg
     file3.jpg
```

Dedup can figure out that `file1.jpg` and `file2.jpg` are the same, so they don't take up more disk space. The btrfs partition is only visible for linux; there would be another drive that's shared with the Windows PCs that can take in the new backup sets.

This would give me a fairly low-cost (below $500) solution with a lot of space and infinite retention time. Online service start at $40/month for this. I could even use btrfs sync to sync all files to another server, in a different physical location.

What am I missing?